# How do I make my user account on my desktop a super user?

Tags: sudo

Hi I am using void linux. In the installation UI when you create a user you have the option to add you user to several groups. In the void handbook says if you add anyone to root group you have complete access over everything. After installation it does not grant me any access. I am not even on the sudoer group.
So, I add my self to the wheel but it does not do what I want.
I do not like sudo and I want my user account to have same privileges as the root user and never have to write sudo for anything. How can I do that?

Comment: Honestly? Probably by not using Linux. Yes, it is possible to do everything as root but it is such a bad idea it really should never be done. You can set a long timeout for your `sudo` password, you can even set some commands to be run as `sudo command` with no password, you can log in as root with `sudo -i` and then run command without `sudo`, but please don't try to "never have to write sudo for anything"

Comment: I'd be root on my DE, I would whine all day long about xorg no longer using /dev/mem & /dev/io, I'd be root on my DE, I would quickly get tired to always type the absolute path of everything, being root on my DE, hmmm, I would almost certainly never get that "fanatic" gold badge on U&L_SE I have always dreamt of… ;-P